# Strings defined in my localization en-us.js will get removed after deploying my SPFx

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint, spfx

I am working on a custom SPFx SharePoint online web part, and we have a localization file named `en-us.js`.. now when i tried to defined new string as follow:-

```
define([], function () {
  return {
ClientPlaceHolder: "Please select client",
ClientLabel: "Client",
//properties goes here
  }
});
```

and then i run these commands:-

```
gulp clean
gulp build
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

but my above modifications to the `en-us.js` will get removed? any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use default web part properties to store settings, do not use en-us.js for settings. The properties are defined in the {YourWebPartName}.manifest.json file, in the section "properties".

Here is a guide how to add them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/simplify-adding-web-parts-with-preconfigured-entries#add-web-part-properties